# Plesk API XML request to get all user details

Tags: plesk

I am working on a PHP script through which I need to connect different Plesk panels (both Windows & Linux) and get the list of all users, their domains, and the resource allocation and usage details.

I could establish connection to Plesk servers and retrieve some data with the support from the Plesk documentation (https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/api-rpc/introduction.79358/).  But I am not getting the exact information I am looking for.  What I need is to get

list of all accounts/users/domains
details of each user
disk & bandwidth quotas set for each domain
disk & bandwidth usage for each domain

I could get XML output for customer details, site details, etc. but I am stuck on the disk and bandwidth quotas/usages.

Can anyone please guide me and help to get the necessary requests to server for obtaining these details?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and multiple tests, I could resolve my issue with the help of Plesk XSD schema - http://plesk.github.io/api-schemas/latest/agent_output.svg

Mentioning it here so that if it could be of help for someone looking for a similar stuff.